# Documentation about compiler options for Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, compiler-optimization, code-documentation

---

Hello, i want to start running some microbenchmarks on Apples Swift-language.
However i feel it is hard to find proper documentation for the different options in regards of compiler optimization.

I have read a lot of questions and articles about other peoples microbenchmarks of the language, however it would be nice to have some firm documentation on the subject.

In the latest beta, the ones to use seems to be:

**-Onone**
No optimizations

**-O**
Safe optimizations?

**-Ounchecked** (Replaced -Ofast)
Unsafe optimizations, (No checks for integer overflow, array out of bounds etc)

My question is, are these all my possible options? And does anybody have some resource that documents this?

**EDIT:**
I have found similar documention to the one i need about objective-c with gcc here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html section 2.8. This is what i need for Swift..